# jQuery Ajax POST error with Firefox and nodejs

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, firefox, post

Im using nodejs and try to send a json to my server. The code works perfectly on chrome, but on firefox Im only get the error callback and nothing happens. I hope you guys have an idea. Im really desperate
The console log:

> "readyState: 0"
>
> "responseText: undefined"
>
> "status: 0"
>
> "text status: error"
>
> "error: "

This is my app.js

```
var db = require('./src/routes/dbconnection');
app.post('/db', db.postJson);
```

This is my script on the server

```
exports.postJson = function (req, res) {
    var message_body = req.body;
    insertIntoDB(message_body);
};

var insertIntoDB = function (message_body) {
    var messages = require('mongoskin').db('localhost:27017', {
        database: 'messages'
    }).collection('header_message');

    messages.insert(message_body, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) console.log('Added!');
    });
}
```

And this is my Ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/db',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        color: color,
        icon: icon,
        message: banner_message,
        leftButtonText: leftButtonText,
        rightButtonText: rightButtonText,
        closeMeButtonOnly: closeMeButtonOnly,
        isEnabled: isEnabled
    },
    success: function () {
        givePopup_success();
        writeMessages();
        showCurrentOne();
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err) {
                console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                console.log("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                console.log("error: " + err);
    }
}).complete(function (data) {
    console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: Your error function receives paramters that contain useful diagnostics, see the jQuery documentation. Print out those diagnostics and you'll have a better idea what's happening.

Comment: So  I tried 

    error: function(xhr,textStatus,err)
    {
    console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
    console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
    console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
    console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
    console.log("error: " + err);
    }

but I only get undefined or "0".

Comment: and did this yield any new information? If so, add it to your question.

Comment: Install the Firebug extension on Firefox, activate Firebug, enable the Net panel in Firebug, then use this panel to analyse the requests and responses to/from the browser. What is logged server side when the call is made from Firefox? Any different from Chrome?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON return empty response on FireFox & Safari (Windows Vista)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341716/json-return-empty-response-on-firefox-safari-windows-vista)

Answer (score 0):

In your `$.ajax` options, use `contentType: 'application/json'` so the server knows what to expect in the data payload. It is better to be explicit.

Also, if you are using the `dataType` option, make sure your server always returns json in its response, even if it is just `{}`. If your server returns nothing, jQuery will think it is an error.

For more info, read the dataType -> json section in the [jQuery ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).